# ckeditor and jquery UI dialog not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ckeditor

I tried endlessly now you resolve this utter frustrating situation I have been having. I am trying to get ckEditor to work within a jQuery UI dialog box. The editor is included perfectly, and it replaces the textarea with the ckeditor skin, but I am unable to edit/add content in the content block. The only working solution I have seen now was if I click on "Source Code" within the editor and unclick it, I am able to add content to it.

My implimentation was purely just `<script type='text/javascript' src='ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script>` and I have not added any additional information / code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue,

removing effects from modal helped :
Removed :

```
show: "scale",
hide: "puff",
```

Now my call looks like this :

```
$("#report").dialog({
        title: "<?php echo caption("REPORT_EDITOR"); ?>",
        bgiframe: true,
          autoOpen: false,
          width: 990,
          height: 620,
          modal: true,

          draggable: true,
          resizable: true,
          resizeStop: function(event, ui) {
              var y = $(event.target).height();
              repEditor.resize( "99%", y - 10 );
          },

          buttons: {
            'Close': function() {
              $(this).dialog('close');
            }
          } 
        });
```

Comment: +1: thanks a lot pal... was doing the every other monkey patching options... :)

Answer (score 2):

For versions of jQuery-UI (1.10+) and jQuery (1.10+), and CKEditor 3.6, [this solution](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9166?cversion=0&cnum_hist=14#comment:14) seems to work:

```
_moveToTop: function( event, silent ) {
    var $parent = this.uiDialog.parent();
    var $elementsOnSameLevel = $parent.children();

    var heighestZIndex = 0;
    $.each($elementsOnSameLevel, function(index, element) {
        var zIndexOfElement = $(element).css('z-index');
        if (zIndexOfElement) {
            var zIndexOfElementAsNumber = parseInt(zIndexOfElement) || 0;
            if (zIndexOfElementAsNumber > heighestZIndex) {
                heighestZIndex = zIndexOfElementAsNumber;
            }
        }
    });
    var currentZIndex = this.uiDialog.css('z-index');

    var moved;
    if (currentZIndex >= heighestZIndex) {
        moved = false;
    } else {
        this.uiDialog.css('z-index', heighestZIndex + 1);
        moved = true;
    }

    if ( moved && !silent ) {
        this._trigger( "focus", event );
    }

    return moved;
}
```

You can either edit the file in-line (not recommended), or just override the default jQuery-UI functionality in a separate JS file that is loaded after jQuery-UI, but before the dialog is created.

```
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    _moveToTop: function( event, silent ) {
        //Logic from above
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to keep the "show" & "hide" animation, create your editor instance after the "show" event finishes with a callback function for the complete: option of "show"

```
$("#report").dialog({
    title: "<?php echo caption("REPORT_EDITOR"); ?>",
    bgiframe: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 990,
      height: 620,
      modal: true,

      // start my suggestion
      show: {
          effect: "scale",
          complete: function() {
            $( "#selector" ).ckeditor();
          }
      },

      hide: "puff",
      // end my suggestion

      draggable: true,
      resizable: true,
      resizeStop: function(event, ui) {
          var y = $(event.target).height();
          repEditor.resize( "99%", y - 10 );
      },

      buttons: {
        'Close': function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      } 
    });
```